# Math extension in mediawiki on windows

Tags: cygwin, mediawiki, tex, mediawiki-extension, mathjax

I want to put some mathematical formulas in a mediawiki install on a local WAMP server. I'm currently trying to install the [math extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Math#Installation) but I can't get it to work.

I've followed the instructions on the MediaWiki wiki, which involve running a script, changing some settings, and installing texvc. On Windows, this last step is quite involved. I found a pre-compiled binary somewhere, but ocaml (which requires installing cygwin), latex and dvipng are required as well. Now with everything installed, when I try texvc, it gives me an error message: "Fatal error: unknown C primitive `unix_getsockopt_bool'"

Does anybody have a suggestion to get LaTeX working on my local WAMP server?

Comment: I don't see any question here, rather a description. What is the question? Otherwise I suspect it will be closed.

Comment: You're right. I edited the description to be a question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The math extension was impossible to get to work. I switched to the MathJAX extension.

Comment: The MathJax extension is deprecated and MathJax is now only available "experimentally" as an option in the math extension.